# Do SVGs have a margin or padding or am I missing something?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am new to using SVGs however I have used sections a lot, and never have I run into this bug. I am trying to get both sections to be flush (vertically) to one another like this: [image: what I want to see]

however, I have a large white space which I assume is a margin or padding on something but I have set both margin and padding to 0px on both SVGs and their parent sections. This is what it looks like:
[image: What I see]
I have tried to remove the padding and margins on all the elements I found that have default properties set (h1 tags and divs) but to no avail.
Here is my HTML:

```
    <section class="first">
        <h1 class="title">Biodiversity Committee</h1>
        <div class="hillcontainer"><img class="hills" src="./assests/hills.svg" /></div>
    </section>
    <section class="second">
        <div class="underhillcontainer"><img class="under-hills" src="./assests/under-hills.svg" /></div>
    </section>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
  .first {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .hillcontainer {
    display: block;
  }
  .hills {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .second {
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .underhillcontainer > svg {
    display: block;
  }
  .under-hills {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: You might need to crack open the SVG source and see if they've added whitespace inside the SVG.

Comment: Just gone through the SVGs and no extra whitespace, cleaned up the excess space in Inkscape, and still nothing, thank you for the suggestion though as it meant I found some extra code in the SVG that I could remove!

Comment: In that case, I might try replacing the SVG's with solid color pngs with the same intrinsic dimensions and see if you have the same problem.  If you do, then it's a CSS layout issue, if you don't, then I might take a look at whether there's a preserveAspectRatio + dimension issue with the SVG's.

Comment: Right, it's a CSS layout issue as the PNGs have the same issue thank you for your help so far, what would you recommend I do?

Comment: I removed the SVG tag and added flexbox and css-position. Should get you the help you need.

Comment: Thank you, just as you posted that I found my own solution, I had accidentally removed position relative from the section and that was causing the issue. Thank you so so much for all the help, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I had accidentally removed `position: relative;` from the section which was causing the issue.

New CSS:

```
.first {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative; /*added line*/
  }
```